# "Failed - Download error" while download a file using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to download a file using selenium but getting "Failed - Download error".

I tried to disable the safe browsing but it didn't work.

I have attached the screenshot and code as well.

logs:

*DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53738/devtools/browser/d75dfd5b-1e3e-45c5-8edd-adf77dd9adb1
[2572:2724:0717/104626.877:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [10:46:26.877] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.*

[image: Error's screenshot]

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import csv
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



link_list = [
"stewartwatson.co.uk", 
"peterkins.com", 
"gavin-bain.co.uk", 
"martinco.com", 
"tmmsolicitors.co.uk", 
"corecitilets.co.uk", 
"coxandco.co", 
"dunechtestates.co.uk", 
"bidwells.co.uk", 
"kwad.co.uk",
]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\\Awais\\projects\\selenium\\web_email_extractor\\csv",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False,
  "safebrowsing.ebabled": "false"
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)


driver.get("https://www.webemailextractor.com")

try:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(),"Close")]').click()
except:
    pass


for i in link_list[0:5]:
    text_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea[@placeholder="Enter domain/websites list"]')
    text_area.send_keys(i)
    text_area.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Extract Email"]').click()
try:
    btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), ' Process Completed')]")))
    time.sleep(3)
    csv_download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="dt-button buttons-csv buttons-html5"]').click()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I removed the "r" from the path

```
"download.default_directory": r"C:\\Users\\Awais\\projects\\selenium\\web_email_extractor\\csv",
```

to:

```
"download.default_directory": "C:\\Users\\Awais\\projects\\selenium\\web_email_extractor\\csv",
```

Comment: That's cause with `r` it's a raw string that will not use escape sequences so `r"\\" == "\\\\"`. Essentially you were doubling up your backslashes.

Answer (score -1):

Dear: When we configure the options of selenium is what will be defined in its configurations and as you write the route so considers it in the first photo you will see a well-configured route and a bad one, note bars there is the difference [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slCQg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UosU6.png)